# Gdb python scripting : No symbol in current contex - even if symbol is there

Tags: python, c, gdb

I have written someGDB python scripts to analyze data containers, but depending on core dump backtrace, some of my class initialization actions fails due to following exception:

```
gdb> my_command Exception: my_cmd_class.__init__(some_init_data) No symbol "A_VALID_ENUM_NAME" in current context.
```

The variable name is definitely there, but in case it's not in scope of current backtrace, gdb is unable to find it for some reason. In case I'll print a listing of the file like:

```
 gdb> list file.c:1
```

, and then repeat a command, the exception is not thrown.

The above workaround is not good though, as it reguires manual intervention (or a good backtrace, but often I don't have such a luxury), so any ideas / suggestions to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a gdb bug (specifically related to lack of symtab expansion in some case); but you haven't really provided enough details to answer this definitively.